# what is the xhr error event object details in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, addeventlistener

I'm testing a simple mobile upload solution - this question is not about the actual upload - in chrome it uploads the pic in firefox the error event fires - so far so good - but now I need why it fires. The event is sent over so surely there is some error info in the object - but I check the spec on the progressevent which I kinda figured out it is sending but I still cant get a error code, description or anything to help me debug - any pointers please?

```
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
function uploadFailed(evt) {
alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
alert(evt.error.toString()); // this is where the trouble starts
// the evt.error is undefined?  
}
```

thnx ;-)

Answer (score 2):

XMLHttpRequest objects have the [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) or the [statusText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText) properties that correspond to the HTTP status of the request. That might be a good starting point. Also checking the JS console and the network tab in the debugger might yield some useful information (especially with CORS issues).

Using the status property, your error handler might look somehow like this:

```
xhr.addEventListener('error', function ()
{
    if (xhr.status >= 500)
    {
        alert("Something went wrong on the server!");
    }
    else if (xhr.status >= 400)
    {
        alert("Something went wrong with the request on our side!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No HTTP error indicated, yet the error event fired?!");
    }
});
```

Comment: thnx @CalmDownVal this helped - I get no HTTP error - so I now tried get USB debug going on the supplied android device with no go (I know USB is ok - Airdroid works) - I don't want to go into an area where this question goes beyond the original scope & tags - currently trying to get the FF web console on the device or something similar to see if there is errors - but still Googling that with no happiness in sight. I'm starting to wonder if Chrome is not better integrated with the device than FF - but on the other hand FF fires up the camera and everything up until the point of upload. Ideas?

Comment: @TheunisPrinsloo not sure about the FF stuff, I only ever used the Chrome debugger connected to an Android device. That aside, you might try to listen for the "abort" event as well, your device might cancel the request for some reason (android apps have lots of weird radio-saving mechanisms, often dependant on individual device's settings)